# SymPy/SciPy: Involving time-dependent values

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I'm new to `SymPy` and `SciPy` and looking for a way to involve time-dependent variables in a symbolic expression.

For example to differentiate *x(t)* with respect to *t* which should result in *xd(t)* or similar.

Up to know I did not find an appropriate example, how to do that?

Comment: Don't try to mix `simpy` and `sympy`, especially when you are new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dynamicsymbols` has an automatic `t` that comes with the symbol, too:

```
>>> from sympy.physics.mechanics import *
>>> dynamicsymbols('x')
x(t)
>>> _.diff(t)
Derivative(x(t), t)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.core.function import Function

t = Symbol('t')
f = Function('f')(t)
print(f)

print("diff(f,t) = %s"%diff(f,t))
print("diff(f,f) = %s"%diff(f,f))
print("diff(f**2,f) = %s"%diff(f**2,f))
```

gives:

```sh
f(t)
diff(f,t) = Derivative(f(t), t)
diff(f,f) = 1
diff(f**2,f) = 2*f(t)
```